# ¿Hay alguna manera de obtener la última página visitada?

Tags: javascript

me gustaría saber si hubiera alguna manera de obtener la última página visitada a través de javascript, he probado el siguiente código:

```
var doblas = window.history.previous.href;
console.log('last page visited:' + doblas);
```

Pero no me devuelve ningún valor

Comment: Te parecería seguro usar un navegador que permitiese a cualquier página web ver tu historial entero del día? Como imaginarás, poca gente usaría un navegador que permitiese acceso total al historial. La mejor manera de ver de dónde viene un usuario cuando entra a tu web es `window.referrer`, ojo, que incluso esto se puede evitar. Pero creo que es la solución más consistente

Comment: @Benito-B la verdad no, es que vi una página web (amiunique.org) donde me dijo mi último sitio visitado, entonces me dio curiosidad jeje

Comment: Por regla general, si accedes a una web a través de un enlace se puede ver en el `referrer`. Por supuesto esto se puede evitar añadiendo `rel=”noreferrer noopener”` a tus enlaces, de esta manera el navegador no rellenará esos atributos y la web a la que accedas no tendrá acceso a nada de la anterior ventana. Si no... bueno, se pueden hacer algunas cochinadas, como acceder a la ventana que abrió la nueva página y modificarle el DOM para añadir lo que quieras. Añadir que si accedes a la web directamente escribiendo tú la URL, obviamente no habrá referrer tampoco